# Using session object in Django unit test

Tags: django, session

I am writing a login view and would like to add a unit test for the view. My view looks like this:

```
def login(request):

    if request.POST:
            usrname = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=usrname, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/core/home/')
            else:
                    context = {'error_message': "Invalid username or password"}
                    return render(request, 'core/login.html', context)
    else:
            c = {}
            c.update(csrf(request))
            return render_to_response('core/login.html',c)

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        context = {'user' : request.user}
        return render(request, 'core/home.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/login.html')
```

And my unit test looks like this:

```
class CoreViewTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
            self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_login_view_with_valid_user(self):
            uf = UserFactory()
            user = uf.make_user("ValidUser1", "12345", "user@abc.com")
            self.assertEqual(user.username, "ValidUser1")
            request = self.factory.post('/core/login', {"username": "ValidUser1", "password": "12345"})
            response = login(request)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The unit test crash because they cannot find the session object. I follow couple tutorial on the websites by defining a dummy session dictionary but it doesn't help.

Can anyone shed some light for me how to write a unit test for a view that need to deal with session object?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your exact code? You have an unclosed dictionary on this line `request = self.factory.post('/core/login', {"username": "ValidUser1", "password": "12345")` - it should be `request = self.factory.post('/core/login', {"username": "ValidUser1", "password": "12345",})`

Comment: Yes it is, I copy my code from the repo. Probably I had a typo when I check in.

Comment: So do you still get the error with the code corrected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation for the `RequestFactory` object:

> It does not support middleware. Session and authentication attributes must be supplied by the test itself if required for the view to function properly.

You could try manually setting `request.session` to be a dictionary with appropriate stuff in it, as you say. It might turn out to be easier to use the old-fashioned [Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#module-django.test.client) though.

Answer (score 1):

Such like this: 
request.session = {'num_visits': 0}

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3.2, using a dictionary did not work for me. I had to use the SessionMiddleware object to process the request and save a session, as shown here:

https://medium.com/@harshvb7/how-to-add-session-and-messages-in-django-requestfactory-16935a3351d0

```html
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.test import RequestFactory


class TestSomeView:
    
    def test_view(self):
        request = RequestFactory().get('/')
        
        # adding session
        middleware = SessionMiddleware()
        middleware.process_request(request)
        request.session.save()
```